# Reconnecting an observable

Tags: javascript, rxjs

It is possible, when I would unsubscribe an connectable observable and at later time to connect it again.

For example:

```
var interval = Rx.Observable.interval(1000);

var source = interval
    .take(2)
    .do(function (x) {
        console.log('Side effect');
    });

var published = source.publish();

published.subscribe(createObserver('SourceA'));
published.subscribe(createObserver('SourceB'));

// Connect the source
var connection = published.connect();

function createObserver(tag) {
    return Rx.Observer.create(
        function (x) {
            console.log('Next: ' + tag + x);
        },
        function (err) {
            console.log('Error: ' + err);
        },
        function () {
            console.log('Completed');
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is. This is exactly what operator `refCount()` does. It subscribes and unsubscribes a ConnectableObservable.

See: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/observable/ConnectableObservable.ts